# How to find out uptime on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, uptime

What is the simplest way to find out how long a computer is turned on Windows?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

- Run command line
- Type Systeminfo
- Find "System Boot Time"

  Days: 10 Hours: 10 Minutes: 10 Seconds: 10

For shorter result you can use:

```
systeminfo | find "Boot Time"
```

Comment: >systeminfo | find "Boot Time"

Comment: for me the simplest way now is > systeminfo | find "Up Time"

Comment: Doesn't work on Vista (use already included uptime.exe instead).

Comment: Also note you can use this to query a remote machine as `systeminfo /S `*machinename*` | find "Up Time"`

Comment: On Windows 7, it shows "System Boot Time" but *not* "System Up Time".

Comment: For Server 2003/XP use "Up Time", anything newer can use "Boot Time".

Comment: Just a note that in the "Boot Time" section the case does matter.  I ran `systeminfo | find "Boot time"` which did not yield results.

Comment: This hasn't worked for a very long time (many years).  It'll return results that say a machine has been up for over 30 days when I know for a fact I turned it off last night and started it up this morning.  Also, there is no "Up Time".  Only "System Boot Time:".  What OS had Up time?

Comment: This is of course working perfectly fine. What you are seeing, @JustinEmlay, is the result of “Fast Startup”. It is enabled by default and means your PC is not really shutting down most of the time, hibernating instead.

Comment: @Daniel B - it's been edited to be correct.  As was stated many years ago "Up Time" no longer exists.  Also, no, Fast Boot or Startup is disabled via Group Policy domain wide.

Comment: Unfortunately the output is localized. For example, in German it''s called "Systemstartzeit". Any possibility to force English output?

Answer (score 15):

there is great command line tool from Microsoft **uptime.exe**:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=BC18FFDB-D6FE-400B-B892-94783AE44C91&displaylang=en

good thing with this tool is it works really fast.

> Uptime [server] [/s ] [/a] [/d:mm/dd/yyyy | /p:n] [/heartbeat] [/? | /help] 
>           server          Name or IP address of remote server to process.
>           /s              Display key system events and statistics.
>           /a              Display application failure events (assumes
>   /s).
>           /d:             Only calculate for events after mm/dd/yyyy.
>           /p:             Only calculate for events in the previous n days.
>           /heartbeat      Turn on/off the system's heartbeat
>           /?              Basic usage.
>           /help           Additional usage information.

Comment: this has been discontinued. [Archvie](http://web.archive.org/web/20100316211056/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243) and [download](http://web.archive.org/web/20091223110128/http://download.microsoft.com/download/winntsrv40/install/uptime_1.01/nt4/en-us/uptime.exe); also [sysinternals psinfo](https://superuser.com/a/103831)

Comment: Works on Windows 10

Answer (score 13):

Open the command prompt and type:

```
net stats srv | find "Statistics"
```

Example output:

```
>net stats srv | find "Statistics"
Server Statistics for \\4IFS-SANDER
Statistics since 22/07/2009 10:14:14
```

Source ([MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555737)).

**Edit**: Actually this will tell you the date and time when the pc was up from, not the duration.

Comment: I'm not sure if this info is correct now, when I use MicTech's and KovBal's solution I get this:
>systeminfo | find "Boot Time"
System Boot Time:          23/07/2009, 02:22:27

Comment: On Vista it returns "Statistics since 1.1.1980 00:00:00" (use already included uptime.exe instead)

Comment: Returns bogus information just like systeminfo.  It's returning a time that I know for a fact the machine last restarted.  But then later that night it was turned off and turned back on this morning.  Yet it's returning the last restarted time.  5 bucks says a month from now it'll report the uptime is a month long.  Lots of machines on my network show many months of uptime which is all bogus.  They're shut off at the end of the day.

Comment: @JustinEmlay are your machines sleeping, hibernated, or shut down?  What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 LTSC 2019.  I found the issue.  Windows 10 no longer shuts down nor restarts properly.  By design.  It uses some funky hybrid sleep mode.  This also makes it so Windows doesn't properly reset "pending reboot" states.  The option to turn it off was in Power Plan Options for one quick version of Windows 10 but then they removed it.  Only way to turn it off is through registry.  Anyway, this is why so many people are having issues.  Local Machine - SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power - HiberbootEnabled - 0

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 and above, this information is displayed in task manager under the "Performance tab".

This can be quicker then using the command line and works in cases where you might have WMI issues preventing you from running systeminfo.

[image: where to find uptiem]

If you need to find this remotely, you could also run

> systeminfo /s SERVERNAME | find "Time:"

from the command line.

Comment: On Windows 7 / SP1 and 2008 / R2, yes.  Not on higher level OS (8, 8.1, 10)

Comment: I have just tested Windows 8.1 (Pro), 2012 and 2016 - what I had to hand.  It is there on all three.  You have to click "More details", and look on the Performance tab.

Comment: And click on the CPU within the performance tab. Just bitten by this :-)

Comment: Bogus information.  I turned my machine on this morning yet it says my Up Time is over 13 days.

Comment: @BlueCompute it's always there in the "Performance" tab in Windows 8, 8.1 and 10

Comment: @JustinEmlay it's not bogus. It's because Windows 10 uses [fast startup](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/what-is-windows-10s-fast-startup/) and doesn't do real shutdown by default and just log out then hibernate the kernel space instead, so uptime is usually very large

Comment: @phuclv nope, that's been disabled domain wide since day 1.  Had no choice but to disable it since it fails to properly reset update reboot flags.  This value does NOT always reset properly.

Answer (score 6):

Following command gives last reboot time for a remote system:

```
systeminfo /s server_name | find "System Boot Time"
```

Answer (score 5):

In windows 10, this is located in Task manager > Expand More Details Chevron > Performance > CPU > At the bottom, Up time.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way:

```
C:\>wmic path Win32_OperatingSystem get LastBootUpTime
LastBootUpTime
20200908203723.500000+120
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Windows Server 2000 or 2003 resource kits try

`srvinfo -ns [\\\server] | Findstr "Time"`

Note: Srvinfo.exe will not run on a 64-bit versions of Windows, due to it being 16-bit.

Answer (score 3):

**Using SYSTEMINFO with PowerShell**

For those who like using PowerShell, you can use the answer(s) above and wrap `systeminfo` in a PowerShell function to get a `DateTime` result for when the server last **booted**:

```
function Get-ComputerBootTime {
  param($ComputerName = (hostname))

  $SystemInfo = & systeminfo /s $ComputerName | Select-String "System Boot Time")
  if($SystemInfo -match "[\d/]+,\s+\S+"){
    return (Get-Date $matches[0])
  }
}
```

And then call the function, for example:

```
[PS]> $BootTime = Get-ComputerUptime -ComputerName MYSERVER
```

To get the **Uptime** for the server, you compare with the current time:

```
[PS]> $UpTime = (Get-Date) - $BootTime
```

This is a `TimeSpan`, which includes properties such as `TotalDays`:

```
[PS]> $UpTime.TotalDays
14.1827364
```

Comment: don't use `systeminfo`. It's extremely slow. Use `Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime` or `Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}` instead

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the uptime is dificult and user is not logged out and the two prety much coincide so I use this command to display the `LOGON TIME`

```
query USER
```

or shorter even:

```
quser
```

which prints something like:

```
C:\Users\eflorinescu>query  USER
 USERNAME                 SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>eflorinescu              console             2  Active    2+23:44  5/7/2018 8:25 AM
```

also even better using PowerShell

```
Get-ComputerInfo | select-object oslastbootuptime
```

Comment: This is when the user logged into the PC which is really different than how long the PC has been on

Comment: @gregg yes you are right but is a quick check if you are never logged out the times are pretty similar, added also the correct PowerShell command

Comment: Thanks, while this isn't exactly what was asked, `query user` is perfectly what I need! Cause I always log in instantly after powering on and I want to know this time. All the other solutions returns the real system boot up time which is (currently) a month ago, due to fast boot - I am not interested in that.

Comment: I forget sometimes to "punch in" (keep track of when I started working for the day) so I can record my hours, so this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Anyone wanting the unix time (seconds since the epoch) that are using cygwin can try this:

```
date +%s -d "$(wmic path Win32_OperatingSystem get LastBootUpTime | grep -E '^[0-9]' | awk '{print substr($1,1,4) "-" substr($1,5,2) "-" substr($1,7,2) " " substr($1,9,2) ":" substr($1,11,2) ":" substr($1,13,2);}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell either of the following commands will work

```powershell
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem |% {$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem).lastbootuptime
```

`Get-CimInstance` is both shorter and more future proof, because `Get-WmiObject` and `wmic` have been both deprecated

You can also run `(Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).lastbootuptime` but the output is less readable because it's a raw time string

See [PowerTip: Get the Last Boot Time with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-get-the-last-boot-time-with-powershell/)