# How to find the uptime in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, windows-xp, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out uptime on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/11287/how-to-find-out-uptime-on-windows)

Is there any function like "Linux uptime" in Windows?

Comment: Care to explain what you are referring, please? If signed up here, you read [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask), which clearly says *> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?*. Did you? If not, I don't see what specifically you're complaining about. By the way: I really don't think such language is necessary, do you?

Answer (score 7):

You can also click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to get to the Task Manager.
In Task Manager, go to the Performance tab. The system uptime is shown under System.

Comment: Only applies to Windows Vista +

Answer (score 5):

[First Google search](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555737/en-us) for "Windows uptime" returned:

**Option 1:**

1. Go to "Start" -> "Run"
2. Write "CMD" and press on "Enter" key
3. Write command `net statistics serve`" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
4. The line that start with `Statistics since …` provides the time that the server was up from

Also command `net stats srv` can be used instead.

**Option 2:**

`Uptime.exe` tool allows you to estimate server availability with Windows NT 4.0 SP4 or higher

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243

Comment: I've used the uptime tool with windows 7, it works pretty well,

Answer (score 3):

I prefer typing

> **systeminfo**

in commandline.