# What's the quickest/easiest way to determine the last time a computer has been restarted?

Tags: windows-7, reboot

From the command line, how do I find when the last time a Windows 7 computer has been restarted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out uptime on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/11287/how-to-find-out-uptime-on-windows), http://superuser.com/questions/377225/how-to-find-the-uptime-in-windows etc. Also see http://superuser.com/questions/564119/windows-8-reports-wrong-uptime-possibly-total-hybrid-boot-uptime for Win8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a Command Prompt by going to Start and opening “cmd”. You will then be presented with a command prompt window, where you need to type the **systeminfo** command below:

```
C:\> systeminfo | find "Boot"
System Boot Time:          05/06/2013, 12:55:07
```

Comment: Note that systeminfo will [drift with sleep and hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uptime#Using_systeminfo).  An alternative is to use [net stats server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555737), which will return faster as it won't have to parse all the Windows Update data.

Answer (score 0):

```
tasklist /v | find "Idle"
```

On Windows 7, **tasklist** will output something (ugly and wrapped) such as:

```
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         24 K Unk
nown         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                   449:12:23 N/A
```

Which in this case means 449 hours (almost 20 days) of system-idle since the last reboot.  Of course, this is a *rough approximation* of time since reboot; it doesn't include actual useful CPU-time.

Comment: Change that to `tasklist /v /fi "pid eq 0" /fo list | find "CPU Time"` and you (a) eliminate the risk that you will stumble across some other process that has `Idle` in its name, and (b) get a less ugly result (that fits generally in 40 characters or fewer).  Note that, either way, this reports the idle ***CPU*** time.  If your system has two CPUs, this can be up to 2× the real elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
net statistics workstation | find "Statistics since"
```

or

```
net statistics server      | find "Statistics since"
```

These commands can be abbreviated  “`net stats work`”  or  “`net stats srv`”.